# Eclipse IDE Note: This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Eclipse IDE Error Message on API method hover.

**Note: This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc.**

I know there are many similar posts but I have Googled and browsed on here for over an hour and still the problem persists.

Everything seems to be in order but still getting this very annoying message. Please help.

Screenshot:
http://pbrd.co/14MAeG8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a JDK, it would be best to set up the Source Location (`src.zip` in your JDK folder) instead of the Javadoc location. Eclipse will extract the JavaDoc from the source and it gives the added benefit of being able to browse the source of the core libraries.

Comment: Normally when you install a JDK it includes the source (`src.zip`); does your JDK have it? Eclipse will automatically detect and configure it, but if you want to do so manually just select the "Source attachment" for `rt.jar` (in your screenshot JRE Definition dialog) and set it to the `src.zip` file in that JDK.